# What open source software can I use to develop interior design software?

Tags: api, ide, 3d-engine

I need to develop an interior designing software :)

Much like a virtual room designing software.

There will be pre-designed 3D objects and they can dragged on to the room. You can change the room size etc... Much like a conventional home designing software :) After the room is designed i should be able to to make the user walk through it...

I know that is a lot of requirements...

But are there any open source IDE's/API's/Engines that can i use to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use depends on the level of realism you want to achieve.

For a simple(ish) start, try [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com) - there is a vast array of samples online: http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/

For something more powerful (and complicated to use), try [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)

You'll then need to use an API to render and allow user movement - for this, take a look at [JMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com)

FYI - There is a more complete list of modeling apps on the [jMonkeyEngine site](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/wiki/doku.php/resources#tools).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really programming related, but look at [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/). It also has a powerful SDK which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

For SDK search for '3d scenegraph' in google. Some good ones are Ogre3d, Irrlicht and OpenSceneGraph. If you are planning on a web based solution you can look at several WebGL based scenegraphs, SceneJS and Google O3D are easy to get started with.